# Hotkeys not working

Tags: boot, usb, shortcut-keys, toshiba

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Toshiba Satellite C55-B5101.

A few weeks ago I was running windows 10, and it froze, so I did a hard shut down. Afterwards it wouldn't turn back on. So now I'm installing Ubuntu on it so I can at least use it.

However, none of the hot-keys are working. I plugged in and installation USB once, and it took me to the installation screen, where it installed, however the first time I tried it said I only had 4.1 GB of memory left, (this is a 500 GB laptop,) and the second time it worked, but it just did the same thing when I tried to reboot it.

And I can't force it to boot from USB, because the hot-keys do nothing. It just boots to a blank screen, and about 20-30 minutes later, it has an error saying there is no boot device.

Is there some way I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try using [boot repair disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/), download the iso and burn it into a usb then try booting into it and repair it. If it doesn't work then try in ubuntu instalation to erase everything and start over

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.